# Using an external storage device on the iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, storage

My iPad Air is severely limited by its storage space.

I do a lot of video recording, and my son bought me an external storage device which I plug into the iPad's Lightning port.

Instead of having to transfer everything to that device, can I record video directly to it? That would be so much easier and save the step of having to record it to the already limited iPad, then transfer it after that to the eternal storage device.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. We can't read your mind and know what app you are using, etc.

Comment: I edited your question to make it easier to understand. However, as @IronCraftMan said, we can't answer for sure until we know more information, such exactly what your storage device is (brand etc.) and what app it requires in order to interface with it.

Answer (score 3):

No - iOS doesn't have a concept of letting you attach permanently storage. When you have an accessory - you'll have to move things that are easily portable (media, etc...) to the external storage and then delete them from the main storage.

Recording goes to the boot volume so you need space there to record.